# Distance of a Robot to Obstacles in a Known Environment

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know this is not a trivial question, but Is there a way in ROS to compute the distance of a robot to the closest obstacle in a known environment.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194545/distance-of-a-robot-to-obstacles-in-a-known-environment/) by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 651 on 2014-10-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Right now, the inflation layer has functionality to figure out how far any point in the costmap is from the closest obstacle. It could extended to just output the distance. This might be the best approach, depending on what kind of application you're looking for.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2014-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0